# accessing an array of arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

in the code below I have created two arrays, both of which are holding arrays.

The first array `testPayloadArray`is supposed to pass the entire array within the i position of the testPayloadArray.

The `runTimeArray`is supposed to pass the array within the i postion of the array and then within that array populate the run time value determinded by the method it is being used in.

My execution is rather incorrect, I admit, I am unsure how to move forward though.

My thought is that[i][j] is the best way to do this. Where i corresponds to the position in the first array and the j corresponds to the position in the second. so if I wanted to populate the third postion in the second array in the runTimeArray the code would look like this, am I correct?

```
runTimeArray[1][2] = endTime - StartTime;
```

code below:

```
ublic class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] sortedDecending = new int[arrayLength];
    int j = 0;
    int k = arrayLength;
    for(int i = arrayLength; i > 0; i--) {
        sortedDecending[j] = k;
        j++;
        k--;
    }
    j = 0;
    int[] sameNum = new int[arrayLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        sameNum[i] = k;
    }
    int[] sortedAssending = new int[arrayLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        sortedAssending[i] = i;
    }

    int[] randomNum = new int[arrayLength];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNum[i] = rand.nextInt(400);
    }
    TestInterface test = new TestInterface(sortedDecending, sameNum, sortedAssending, randomNum);
    test.runTest();

}

public void runTest(){
  int[][] testPayloadArray ={this.sortedDecending, this.sameNum, this.sortedAssending, this.randomNum};
  long[][] runTimeArray = {bubbleSortRunTime, selectionSortRunTime, insertionSortRunTime,
  quicksortRunTime, quicksort2RunTime, mergesortRunTime, mergesort1RunTime, heapsortRunTime};

  for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
      runBubbleSort(i, runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runSelectionSort(i, runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runInsertionSort(i, runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runQuickSort(i,runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runQuickSort2(i, runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runMergeSort(i, runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runMergeSort1(i,runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
      runHeapSort(i, runTimeArray[i], testPayloadArray[i]);
  }
  testReport();
```

Comment: Yes `runTimeArray[1][2]` represents the 3rd position in 2nd array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  `runTimeArray[1][2]` represents 3rd position in 2nd array.

Also, For Your sortedDescending array, you can probably just have following loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    sortedDescending[i] = arraylength - i;
}
```

Also, if you just want to just store the execution time in your runTimeArray you can change the signature of each sort methods to return the time and store it in your loop directly.

so, for example your loop can be like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  runTimeArray[i][0] = runBubbleSort(testPayloadArray[i]);
  runTimeArray[i][1] = runSelectionSort(testPayloadArray[i]);
}
```

and the methods could be like

```
private long runSelectionSort(int[] ints) {

  return endTime - StartTime;;
}

private long runBubbleSort(int[] ints) {
  return endTime - StartTime;;
}
```